# Improve performance when sorting and reading JSON from file C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, performance, deserialization

I have a JSON file that contains about 20k lines of code that has to be read, sorted and saved into a database. I've written code for it and it works the way it's suppose to but my issue is that it takes about 10 minutes. Therefor I wonder if someone has any ideas what can be done to enhance the performance?

Json:

```
{
    "Number": 123456,
    "Area": "NE01"
},
{
    "Number": 123457,
    "Area": "NE01"
},
```

and so forth....

C#:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8));

foreach (var obj in json)
{
    if (obj.Area == "NE01")
    {
        var o = new object
        {
            Number = obj.Number,
        };
        db.Entity.Add(obj);
        continue;
    }

    if (obj.Area == "NE02")
    {
        var o = new object
        {
            Number = obj.Number,
        };
        db.Entity.Add(obj);
        continue;
    }

    if (obj.Area == "NE03")
    {
        var o= new object
        {
            Number = obj.Number,
        };
        db.Entity.Add(obj);
        continue;
    }

    if ( obj.Area== "NE04")
    {
        var o = new object
        {
            Number = obj.Number
        };
        db.Entity.Add(obj);
        continue;
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

To make it clearer, area has four different values. Depending on the value the number will have a foreign key that points to the area. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change anything in the underlying database.
Let me know if I have to provide further information.

Comment: Have you added timings to see where the time is going? there are 4 places to time, as a start: `File.ReadAllText`, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, the `foreach` loop, and finally `SaveChanges`. Until you know where the time is being spent: you can't start to make it faster.

Comment: might take a look at the bulk operations - EF  do not support it. In case SaveChanges is slow

Comment: That's not valid Json.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I think we can infer that it is an *extract* from the JSON, presumably from a JSON array; I'm not sure that's something we need to get hung up on...

Comment: @MarcGravell: Probably. It would still have been better to display the whole structure of the Json to get better answers.

Comment: to echo @Vladimir: if *all* you're doing here is insert, then `SqlBulkCopy` may be your best option. There's interesting ways of doing that, but perhaps the most *convenient* (if you have a `List<T>` of a `T` that looks like the table) is to use `FastMember.ObjectReader` look for `bcp` here: https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member

Comment: Ef addRange could be enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only by using AddRange I was able to decrease the time to just over one minute. Which is good enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Using [EntityFramework.Utilities](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities) you can use Bulk Insert which should speed up insertions.

Something like:

```
public class Data
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
  public string Area { get; set; }
}

var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8))
  .Select(d => new object { Number = d.Number })
  .ToList();

EFBatchOperation.For(db, db.Entity).InsertAll(objects);
```

*Disclaimer: **Code not tested.***